# Why does the data in my cookie come back as undefined?

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

What I'm trying to do is set a json web token into a cookie. When I console.log(token) it's defined, but when I get the cookie it's undefined. I've tried moving the res.cookie call to a few different places and I'm still getting it as undefined

POST request

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const { errors, isValid } = validateLoginInput(req.body);
    if (!isValid) {
        return res.status(400).json(errors);
    }

    const { email, password } = req.body;
    User.findOne({ email })
        .then(user => {
            if (!user) return res.status(400).json({
                msg: 'User does not exist',
                auth: false
            });

            //Validate password
            bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
                .then(isMatch => {
                    if (!isMatch) return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Invalid credentials' });

                    const token = jwt.sign(
                        { id: user.id },
                        process.env.JWT_SECRET,
                        (err, token) => {
                            if (err) throw err;
                            res.json({
                                token,
                                user: {
                                    id: user.id,
                                    name: user.name,
                                    email: user.email,
                                    auth: true
                                }
                            })
                            console.log(token)
                            res.cookie('access_token', token, {
                                maxAge: 604800,
                                httpOnly: true,
                                // secure: true
                            })
                        }
                    )
                })
        })
})
```

Comment: Did you look at a resonse's `Set-Cookie` header in browser's dev tools?

Comment: I did. That's where I found that it was undefined

Comment: Did you try to set cookie before `res.json`?

Comment: I just tried it and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `res.cookie` before `res.json`. I suppose you should have seen a warning about setting headers after response is about to send.

Comment: I never got that warning, but I did exactly that and it worked. Thanks a bunch